# How can I deduplicate the following code based on a condition that rebinds a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How should I deduplicate this code (simplified):

```
root = # some node in a binary tree
item = # some item that gets stored with a node

# The code that I want to deduplicate (insert into binary tree)
current_node = root
while current_node:
    if current_node.mark > item:
        if current_node.left:
            current_node = current_node.left
        else:
            current_node.left = Node(item)
            break

    # the same thing but with current_node.right :(
    elif current_node.mark < item:
        if current_node.right:
            current_node = current_node.right
        else:
            current_node.right = Node(item)
            break
```

In C++, I would do this:

```cpp
auto& dir_node = current_node.mark > item ? current_node.left : current_node.right;
```

and then just use `dir_node` where I'm using `current_node.left/right`. But Python doesn't have references. If I do:

```
dir_node = current_node.left if current_node.mark > item else current_node.right
```

it works fine but just for the if part. It doesn't work for the else part because as far as I can understand, I'm rebinding `dir_node`, and not actually modifying the object `dir_node` references. That's better than what I have right now, but still duplicates a bit.

So my question is: What can I do to deduplicate this code?